# "Come closer" or "Come nearer"?

Tags: word-request

should we say "sleep close to me" or "Sleep near me" or "don't sit close to the TV" or "don't sit near to the TV". Normally we should say "Come closer" or "Come nearer"?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://fandom-grammar.livejournal.com/41307.html

Answer (score 1):

In all your examples, the word "close" seems to be the most appropriate and common word for that phrase. If you said "near" instead, it would be a bit unusual.

For example: "don't sit too close to the TV", because it's bad for your eyes. That's ordinary usage.  If you said "don't sit near the TV", because it might blow up.  What??  Well, an unusual directive for an unusual situation.

Or, "come closer" because I love you. Or "Come nearer", said the witch to the boy, so that I can cast a spell on you.  Again an unusual directive for an unusual situation.

However, it's not that "near" is always the less common word. Only in these particular examples. The positions might be reversed in other sentences, where "near" would be the expected word, and then saying "close" would indicate a special case.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Then "Sleep close to me" would be correct instead of "sleep near me", right? My kids always requested mummy to sleep closer to them.